# Passanger door central locking not working properly

Tags: hyundai, locks, door, elantra

I have a 1998 Hyundai Elantra 1.6 GLS and I'm having problems with the central locking. When I lock the car the passengers front door does not lock properly and it only locks half way but does not pull all the way in.
I have lubricated all the linkages and it seems free and loose but I don't know what else to to do now. Is there something else I can look at to correct this issue?

Comment: The door handles and locking mechanisms have been a huge issue on my Hyundai/ Kia. Can you describe exactly what's malfunctioning?

Comment: Can you manually lock the passenger front door?

Comment: Can you access the motor that locks the door, see if it pulls, free it from the linkage and see the same then try if it has any strength while holding the arm with your fingers? If its the motor and you lock the door with your key chances are it wont be able to open the lock either, could you try?